# query through refTabels

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine

i got this tabels

Users:

```
id name
1 | tom
2 | jim
3 | bob
```

User_Has_Toys

```
user_id toy_id
1      | 2
1      | 3
1      | 4
2      | 2
2      | 4
3      | 4
```

Toy

```
id name
1 | toy1
2 | toy2
3 | toy3
4 | toy4
5 | toy5
```

and i make query

```
SELECT u.id FROM Users u
LEFT JOIN User_Has_Toys uht ON (u.id = uht.user_id)
LEFT JOIN Toy t ON t.id = uht.toy_id
WHERE t.id IN ('2', '4')
```

and i get all users
but i need only users with id 1 and 2

could some one help me?

Comment: Should be ... WHERE u.id = 2 AND u.id = 4 instead of t.id IN ('2', '4')

Comment: no, i need to get user which necessarily has toy2 and toy4

Comment: Please, be clearer. Did you mean "toy2 and toy4" or "toy2 OR toy4"? Because in your example you went for the latter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method to check if a user has multiple specific rows in another table is to filter for those rows and see if count is correct.  So for instance, if we count the number of rows in User_Has_Toys for a specific user id and filtering for toys 2 and 4, we should get a count of 2 if and only if the user has both toys 2 and 4 (**NOTE: assuming duplicate toy entries are not allowed**).  The query would look something like this:

```
 SELECT 
     u.id
 FROM Users AS u
    WHERE 2 = (
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM User_Has_Toys uht
        WHERE uht.toy_id IN (2,4)
        AND uht.user_id = u.id);
```

Demo: http://sqlize.com/6yU3OlU2pD

You could also get the same result with a minor modification to your original query by grouping by the user id and checking that the toy count is exactly 2:

```
SELECT u.id FROM Users u
LEFT JOIN User_Has_Toys uht ON (u.id = uht.user_id)
LEFT JOIN Toy t ON t.id = uht.toy_id
WHERE t.id IN ('2', '4')
group by u.id having count(t.id) = 2;
```

Demo: http://sqlize.com/7nTYZbJKsn

Comment: its so simple :)
really thantx.

Answer (score 1):

```
 DECLARE @User TABLE
 (
UserID INT NOT NULL,
Name VARCHAR(128)
 )

 DECLARE @User_Has_Toys TABLE
 (
    UserID INT NOT NULL,
ToyID INT NOT NULL
 )

 DECLARE @Toys TABLE
 (
ToyID INT NOT NULL,
ToyName VARCHAR(128)
 )

 INSERT INTO @User (UserID, Name) VALUES (1,'Tom')
 INSERT INTO @User (UserID, Name) VALUES (2,'Jim')
 INSERT INTO @User (UserID, Name) VALUES (3,'Bob')

 INSERT INTO @User_Has_Toys (UserID, ToyID) VALUES (1,2)
 INSERT INTO @User_Has_Toys (UserID, ToyID) VALUES (1,3)
 INSERT INTO @User_Has_Toys (UserID, ToyID) VALUES (1,4)
 INSERT INTO @User_Has_Toys (UserID, ToyID) VALUES (2,2)
 INSERT INTO @User_Has_Toys (UserID, ToyID) VALUES (2,4)
 INSERT INTO @User_Has_Toys (UserID, ToyID) VALUES (3,4)

 INSERT INTO @Toys (ToyID, ToyName) VALUES (1,'Toy1')
 INSERT INTO @Toys (ToyID, ToyName) VALUES (2,'Toy2')
 INSERT INTO @Toys (ToyID, ToyName) VALUES (3,'Toy3')
 INSERT INTO @Toys (ToyID, ToyName) VALUES (4,'Toy4')
 INSERT INTO @Toys (ToyID, ToyName) VALUES (5,'Toy5')


 SELECT 
 u.UserID,
 u.Name,
 uht.ToyID,
 t.ToyName
 FROM @User AS u
 LEFT JOIN @User_Has_Toys AS uht ON u.UserID = uht.UserID
 LEFT JOIN @Toys AS t ON t.ToyID = uht.ToyID
 WHERE uht.ToyID IN (2,4)

 This one is good for SQL Server 2008 r2 
 don't mind the temp tables I've just used them to represent you're sample table.
```

Comment: inner join do not help
i think the problem is in `WHERE t.id IN ('2', '4')`

Comment: @AllanChua: Please be aware there are *numerous* differences between SQL Server and MySql.  Here is what your code **should** be in MySql: http://sqlize.com/Gh5y7ve1Yo